# Weighted Matrix summation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

My goal :
calculate w_1*A_1+w_2*A_2+...+w_n*A_n
where w_1, ... ,w_n are scalar
A_1, ... , A_n are M x M matrix

So if W is (n,1) array and A is (n,M,M) array,then

I know that it can be done by such code

```
temp=np.zeros((M,M),dtype=np.float)
for i in range(n):
  temp=temp+W[i]*A[i]
```

However, this requires many time. I want to calculate this more faster via use numpy library.

For example, A_1+A_2+...+A_n can be done by

```
np.sum(A,axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% that I understand what you are after, but from what I understand this could be done with [tensortdot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html)

```python
import numpy as np

A = [
  [
    [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    [ 4, 5, 6 ],
    [ 7, 8, 9 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    [ 4, 5, 6 ],
    [ 7, 8, 9 ]
  ]
]

W = [ 1, 2 ]

print(np.tensordot(np.transpose(W), A, axes=1))

> [[ 3  6  9]
   [12 15 18]
   [21 24 27]]
```